# Why does my htaccess dislike this URL?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I hope someone can help me with this.

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

A URL like the following will successfully rewrite:

```
http://jobs2.local/main/out/16339404/http://www.google.com/
```

However if I encode the URL last part of the URL (the http://www.google.com/ part) I get a 404 error:

```
http://jobs2.local/main/out/16339404/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F
```

The culprit appears to be the %2F but I do not understand why this is happening.

Do any of you know what the problem is?

Thank you.

Comment: This would be more appropriate for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com, it's off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.

The problem is Apache does not like %2F.

The solution is to add "AllowEncodedSlashes On" to the VirtualHost entry in httpd.conf for the website, e.g.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    AllowEncodedSlashes On
    ServerName jobs2.local
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

I have tested this and it works as expected.